# How to instantiate/call java class with parameter from PHP?

Tags: java, php, jasper-reports, php-java-bridge

For example, i have java class JRXlsExporter, if i instantiated that java from java my code is :

```
    JRXlsExporter myObject= new JRXlsExporter();
```

and from PHP become:

```
    $myObject = new Java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter");
```

It works, but if i have java class with parameter, for example :

```
    JRXlsExporter myObject= new JRXlsExporter(param1,param2);
```

How to instantiate/call that java class from PHP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [an example](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wsmashin/v1r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.sMash.doc/using/zero.php/ZeroAdvancedPHPJavaBridge.html) of how `java.util.Date` object is instantiated, with some constructor arguments:

```
$date = new Java("java.util.Date", 70, 9, 4);
```

Further, it says:

> The new Java("java.util.Date", 70, 9, 4) call creates a new instance of the java.util.Date class using the java.util.Date(int year, int month, int day) constructor.

So, you could maybe try this:

```
$myObject = new Java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter", param1, param2);
```