# Passing parameters from php javabridge JasperReports

Tags: java, php, jasper-reports, php-java-bridge

I'm working with javabridge and I get this warning and error:

```
 ( ! ) Warning: Unchecked exception detected: [[o:Response$UndeclaredThrowableErrorMarker]:"FATAL: Undeclared java.lang.RuntimeException detected. java.lang.Exception: CreateInstance failed: new java.util.Date((o:String)[o:String]). Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException VM: 1.7.0_79@http://java.oracle.com/" at: #-11 java.util.Date.parse(Unknown Source) #-10 java.util.Date.<init>(Unknown Source) #-9 sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) #-8 sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl[...]java/Java.inc(361): java_Arg->getResult(false) #2 http://localhost:8080/JavaBridgeTemplate/java/Java.inc(364): java_Client->getWrappedResult(false) #3 http://localhost:8080/JavaBridgeTemplate/java/Java.inc(536): java_Client->getInternalResult() #4 http://localhost:8080/JavaBridgeTemplate/java/Java.inc(1930): java_Client->createObject('java.util.Date', Array) #5 C:\wamp\www\advanced\backend\javabridge\generate.php(48): Java->Java('java.util.Date', '2016-07-01') #6 {main}] in http://localhost:8080/JavaBridgeTemplate/java/Java.inc on line 202
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0040  324624  {main}( )   ..\generate.php:0
2   3.3043  1428168 Java->Java( )   ..\generate.php:48
3   3.3043  1429240 java_Client->createObject( )    ..(null):1930
4   3.3113  1429512 java_Client->getInternalResult( )   ..(null):536
5   3.3113  1429560 java_Client->getWrappedResult( )    ..(null):364
6   3.3113  1429560 java_Arg->getResult( )  ..(null):361
7   3.3113  1441256 java_ThrowExceptionProxyFactory->checkResult( ) ..(null):235
8   3.3163  1444344 trigger_error ( )   ..(null):202

Fatal error: Uncaught [[o:Exception]:"java.lang.Exception: Invoke failed: [[c:JasperFillManager]]->fillReport((o:JasperReport)[o:JasperReport], (i:Map)[o:HashMap], (i:Connection)[o:Connection]). Cause: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Incompatible php.java.bridge.Response$UndeclaredThrowableErrorMarker value assigned to parameter FInicio in the Reubicados dataset. VM: 1.7.0_79@http://java.oracle.com/" at: #-17 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setParameter(JRFillDataset.java:903) #-16 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setFillParameterValues(JRFillDataset.java:642) #-15 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setParameterValues(JRFillDataset.java:585) #-14 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1280) #-13 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:901) #-12 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845) #-11 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:58) #-10 net.sf.ja in http://localhost:8080/JavaBridgeTemplate/java/Java.inc on line 195
```

In my php file the code that launches this error is when I try to pass date parameters to JasperReports's report creating an instance of java.util.date class:

```
require_once("http://localhost:8080/JavaBridgeTemplate/java/Java.inc");

try {
    $Param1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['FInicio']));
    $Param2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['FFin']));
    $fecha1=date_create("2016-01-15");
    $fecha2=date_create("2016-08-15");
    $date1 = date_format( $fecha1, 'Y-m-d');             
    $date2 = date_format( $fecha2, 'Y-m-d');             

    $jasperxml = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader");
    $jasperDesign = $jasperxml->load(realpath("Reubicados.jrxml"));
    $query = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignQuery");

    $jasperDesign->setQuery($query);
    $compileManager = new JavaClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager");
    $report = $compileManager->compileReport($jasperDesign);
} catch (JavaException $ex) {
    echo $ex;
}    

$fillManager = new JavaClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager");
    //aqui se pasan los parametros (Fecha Inicio y Fecha Fin)
    $params = new Java("java.util.HashMap");

$params->put("FInicio",new Java('java.util.date', $Param1));
$params->put("FFin",new Java('java.util.date', $Param2));
```

Here is the *jrxml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Reubicados" language="groovy" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="552" leftMargin="30" rightMargin="30" topMargin="15" bottomMargin="5">
    <parameter name="FInicio" class="java.util.Date">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="FFin" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[some query]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ayudante_situacion_laboral_FechaInicio" class="java.sql.Date"/>
    <field name="ayudante_situacion_laboral_FechaFin" class="java.sql.Date"/>
    <field name="ayudante_situacion_laboral_Cant_Horas" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="ayudante_situacion_laboral_Descripcion" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ayudante_Registro" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="ayudante_Nombre" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="situacion_laboral_Estado" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="SUM" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Group" resetGroup="nombreGroup" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{ayudante_situacion_laboral_Cant_Horas}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="nombreGroup">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{ayudante_Nombre}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="1">
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="488" height="1"/>
                </line>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="488" y="0" width="61" height="1"/>
                </line>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <title>
        <band height="93">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="70" width="549" height="23"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Carretera de la Subplanta No.76 e/Alambique y CalleC. Rpto SubPlanta,SantaClara, VillaClara,Cuba.
Teléfonos: 204782 Fax: 202753 Email: gustavo@ecvcl.cupet.cu
]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <image>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="248" y="0" width="156" height="70"/>
                <imageExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\yanet\\Desktop\\logo.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="64">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="549" height="44"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[MODELO DE REUBICADOS
UEB DE TRANSPORTE
GRUPO DE TRÁFICO
]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="44" width="404" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Tabla # 1. Relación de Reubicados del mes de: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="47" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Registro]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="258" y="0" width="38" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Horas]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="189" y="0" width="69" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Día]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="296" y="0" width="192" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Actividad]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="47" y="0" width="142" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Nombre y Apellidos]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="488" y="0" width="61" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Total]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="21">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="47" height="21"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" lineSpacing="Single"/>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="47" y="0" width="142" height="21"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" lineSpacing="Single"/>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="47" height="21">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{nombreGroup_COUNT}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{ayudante_Registro}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="###0.00">
                <reportElement x="258" y="0" width="38" height="21"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{ayudante_situacion_laboral_Cant_Horas}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="47" y="0" width="142" height="21">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{nombreGroup_COUNT}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{ayudante_Nombre}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="296" y="0" width="192" height="21"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{ayudante_situacion_laboral_Descripcion}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="488" y="0" width="61" height="21"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" lineSpacing="Single"/>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField evaluationTime="Group" evaluationGroup="nombreGroup">
                <reportElement x="488" y="0" width="61" height="21">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{nombreGroup_COUNT}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$V{SUM}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="dd/MM">
                <reportElement x="189" y="0" width="69" height="21"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{ayudante_situacion_laboral_FechaInicio}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="136">
            <image>
                <reportElement x="485" y="30" width="64" height="96"/>
                <imageExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\yanet\\Desktop\\3.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="248" y="32" width="146" height="94"/>
                <imageExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\yanet\\Desktop\\2.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="404" y="42" width="81" height="68"/>
                <imageExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\yanet\\Desktop\\2.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="552" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Elaborado: Alexander F. Meneses Mederos                  Aprobado:
                      Técnico “A” Transporte                                                Jefe de Tráfico
]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in PHP-Java bridge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25892337/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-in-php-java-bridge)

Comment: Yanet, you should use the right class name: `java.util.Date`, not the `java.util.date` like in your code. Java is case sensitive. The valid code is:  `$params->put("FInicio",new Java('java.util.Date', $Param1))`

Comment: Alex, Lot of new errors. Should I edit entry and add it?

Comment: It depends on error :). It is better to post a new question if it something really new

Comment: I added it. I think it has to do with parameters

Comment: `CreateInstance failed: new java.util.Date((o:String)[o:String])` - You are instantiated the parameter wrong. BTW, your question's body is irrelevant to the problem. It is a bad idea to edit the post to ask a new question

Comment: It is not a very good solution (because this type of constructor is deprecated), but... [How to instantiate/call java class with parameter from PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13247418/876298). At your code the *String* object is passing to the Java *java.util.Date* object

Comment: How can I pass a date Object. I use strtotime above and it still appears as a String object.

Comment: I'm not a php expert. You can try to ask a new question `"How to pass java.util.Date to Java library with help of php-java bridge"` with *php*, *java* and *php-java-bridge* tags with sample you have. Another way is to try a solution from the link I posted you in my previous comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128487/discussion-between-yanet-pedraza-and-alex-k).